# Zend Famework how to set action for a form (to validate on the same page) that appears in all pages

Tags: zend-framework

I have a form (login form) that appears in all pages (if the user is not logged in).

[image]

The form is created from view helper and then directly called in layout.phtml

```
class Zend_View_Helper_LoginForm extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
public function loginForm()
{

    $login = new Application_Form_Login();
    return $login;

}

}    


<?php if(!$this->isLoggedIn()): ?>          
        <div id="login">
            New User? <a href="#">Register Here</a>
            <?php echo $this->loginForm(); ?>
            <a href="#">Forgot Password!</a>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Now how to set the action of this form such that i could validate the fields in the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we usually do is that we send the form to different action and have dedicated form rendered in that actions view. If there is no error, user is redirected without noticing. If there is an error, the form is dispalyed in main content area with proper error messages. Usualy the problem is that the area of this form vidget is not big enough for good error message.

Comment: @Thomas yes i have a separate login form page. But this widget would still appear in the login display page.

Comment: some how managed to do this. Sorry other guys but this worked for me :(!!

Answer (score 2):

Matthew Weier O'Phinney (the ZF Programmer leader ) has a blogpost about creating your reusable widget exactly like your needs

you should try it ,

http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html

Answer (score 1):

You can validate it on other page and redirect back after validation. Also, you can validate it through ajax.

Comment: i think ajax sounds better ... but never used ajax on zend.

Answer (score 0):

usually you post it to login page and if you fail you can redirect user back, set proper http header and display a error message

Comment: In that case i will not be using the zend inbuilt validator message